# Convert python ndarray to matlab matrix

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, numpy

I am calling from matlab (R2015b) a python module that I created. Now I've noticed that, we can only send to python a 1xN vector.

So I fixed this in Matlab

Matlab Code:

```
a = ones(3, 3);
a = a(:).';
```

Then I sent `a` as parameter to python function.

```
 m = py.computeCoreset.computecoreset(a, obj.coresetSize);
```

Now my problem that python doesn't return Matlab matrix
I noticed that I am returning an ndarray while debugging.

This is my python code:

```
import numpy as np


def computecoreset(mat, coresetSize):
    return np.random.choice(mat, coresetSize)
```

I guess I need to make the ndarray a matrix once again

But how do I convert it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you use the function that you show?

Comment: Your Python code obviously returns a numpy array, but doesn't the interface code create some sort of MATLAB object from that?  A numpy array can't exist in a MATLAB environment.  Elaborate on how you call the Python code from MATLAB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/157347-convert-python-numpy-array-to-double

The accepted answer suggests  `py.array.array` function:

```
data = double(py.array.array('d',py.numpy.nditer(x)));
```

Which is also listed on

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/handling-data-returned-from-python.html

Comment: I think the point of using `nditer(x)` is to serialize the elements of `x` into a 1-d sequence.  In this case, `x` is 1-d, so I don't think using `nditer()` is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

This is a shot in the dark, because I don't have Matlab to test it, but I suspect you'll have to return a python [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) object, not a numpy array.
So something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import array


def computecoreset(mat, coresetSize):
    c = np.random.choice(mat, coresetSize)
    return array.array('d', c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, the other way goes like this:

```matlab
rnd = rand(5);
py.numpy.asarray(rnd)


  Python ndarray:

    0.3112    0.6541    0.2290    0.9961    0.0046
    0.5285    0.6892    0.9133    0.0782    0.7749
    0.1656    0.7482    0.1524    0.4427    0.8173
    0.6020    0.4505    0.8258    0.1067    0.8687
    0.2630    0.0838    0.5383    0.9619    0.0844

    Use details function to view the properties of the Python object.

    Use double function to convert to a MATLAB array.
```