Convert ndarray with structure in Matlab
I am testing to call a Scipy function of Decimate from Matlab and get a ndarray from this function with structure as below
y_data =
Python ndarray with properties:
       T: [1×1 py.numpy.ndarray]
    base: [1×1 py.numpy.ndarray]
  ctypes: [1×1 py.numpy.core._internal._ctypes]
    data: [1×61 py.memoryview]
   dtype: [1×1 py.numpy.dtype[float64]]
   flags: [1×1 py.numpy.flagsobj]
    flat: [1×1 py.numpy.flatiter]
    imag: [1×1 py.numpy.ndarray]
itemsize: [1×1 py.int]
  nbytes: [1×1 py.int]
    ndim: [1×1 py.int]
    real: [1×1 py.numpy.ndarray]
   shape: [1×1 py.tuple]
    size: [1×1 py.int]
 strides: [1×1 py.tuple]

[ 5.99081382e-03  5.83549240e-01  9.51130546e-01  9.48473537e-01
  5.86508837e-01  1.02585620e-03 -5.88140511e-01 -9.47959932e-01
 -9.50266816e-01 -5.86279197e-01  5.24797354e-05  5.86330487e-01
  9.49823174e-01  9.48834128e-01  5.87047010e-01 -1.59869334e-04
 -5.86712088e-01 -9.49194165e-01 -9.49481760e-01 -5.86544283e-01
 -1.19347373e-04  5.86767698e-01  9.49307038e-01  9.49280786e-01
  5.86755373e-01 -4.55924399e-05 -5.86674972e-01 -9.49330026e-01
 -9.49305409e-01 -5.86712712e-01  1.02337656e-05  5.86690123e-01
  9.49332521e-01  9.49300839e-01  5.86697807e-01  4.20505327e-05
 -5.86784485e-01 -9.49211137e-01 -9.49413536e-01 -5.86643745e-01
  1.30050483e-05  5.86588130e-01  9.49543168e-01  9.49003229e-01
  5.87021587e-01 -2.10799396e-04 -5.86717779e-01 -9.48992721e-01
 -9.49956824e-01 -5.85832688e-01 -8.98924013e-04  5.87341478e-01
  9.49239365e-01  9.48646598e-01  5.88253289e-01 -2.43631403e-03
 -5.83370405e-01 -9.52366021e-01 -9.49453473e-01 -5.88127079e-01
 -1.23584431e-02]

How to convert this structure into Matlab format? Or simply put the data into a Matlab array?
Thanks in advance.
I have tried to use Matlab command
double, struct, evalc ([' disp(y_data) '])


Have you tried the suggestions in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40295287/convert-python-ndarray-to-matlab-matrix

that looks like a normal 1d array of floats with 61 elements.

Thanks for the comments from Nick and hpaulj. I find the solution as below double(py.numpy.asarray(y_data))) for anybody having the same question

Thanks for the comments from Nick and hpaulj. I find the solution as below double(py.numpy.asarray(y_data))) for anybody having the same question.

If y_data is an ndarray, then np.asarray(y_data) does nothing. Just double(y_data) should work.
